# Telegram bot ChatInviteLink

Tags: bots, telegram

I managed to use the createChatInviteLink function but I don't know how to extract the invitation link to send to the user.

```
function create_chat_link(chat_id){
  chat_id = ‘chat_id';
  max_usos = 1;
  var url = telegramUrl + '/createChatInviteLink?chat_id=' + chat_id + '&member_limit=' + max_usos;
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}
```

How can I extract the link that is generated when using that method?

Answer (score 0):

When using Telegram Bot API you will receive a json formatted response upon calling your url.
In your case for `createChatInviteLink` method this response will look something like this:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": {
    "invite_link": "https://t.me/+fLsUa7gOGDxjOOA2",
    "creator": {
      "id": 210111457,
      "is_bot": true,
      "first_name": "...",
      "username": "..."
    },
    "creates_join_request": false,
    "is_primary": false,
    "is_revoked": false
  }
}
```

Check `invite_link` field to find your invitation link.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot. Now, when I have the link, the + sign is removed and I have something like this.
https://t.me/ fLsUa7gOGDxjOOA2
The + sign is removed from the link